# Main difference between ListView notifiDataSetChanged() and notifiDataSetInvalidated()

Tags: android, android-listview

I know `ListAdapter.notifiDataSetChanged()` calls `DataSetObserver.onChanged()` and `ListAdapter.notifiDataSetInvalidated()` calls `DataSetObserver.onInvalidated()`. But I don't really know how they affects ListViews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateSetInvalidated invalidates your scroll position and your selections.
You basically saying that Adapters old state is no longer valid.